# C, minus operator in multiply

Tags: c, operators

The question concerns implicit multiplication by the `-` operator.
For example

```
float a = 10;
float b;
```

`b = -a;` Is this valid? does `b = -10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't implicit multiplication, but use of the unary `-` operator.

The code is valid, since the operator works on all arithmetic types, including floating point.